# FOSUserBundle. Include login form in my template

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

Hi I'm trying to include the login form of the FOSUser Bundle in my custom template. Like that:

```
 {% include 'FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig' %}
```

But I have this error:
`Variable "error" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig at line 7`

Is there a way to include the template without adding something in my controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To overriding FosUserBundle's template you have to do this :

1. Create a folder `FOSUserBundle/view` in `app/Resources`
2. Copy the view folder of FOSUserBundle in your folder you have create just before

And you can include your template and custom FOSUser view.

Example :

**layout.html.twig** of FOSUser in  `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/view`:

```
{% extends ":layout:Public/layout.html.twig" %} #My layout
{% block body %}
        <div>
            {% block fos_user_content %}

            {% endblock fos_user_content %}
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

And `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/view/Security/login.html.twg` :

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Se connecter </h2>
        <hr>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
        <label class="sr-only" for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
        <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />
        <label class="sr-only" for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" placeholder="Mot de passe" />
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
                <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Mot de passe perdu ?</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h2>Pas encore inscrit ?</h2>
    <hr>
    <em>
        nous vous invitons à vous inscrire<br />
    </em>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" class="btn btn-primary">S'inscrire</a>
</div>


{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

I think there is many solutions, but according to me it's the better way to overrinding fosuser's views

Answer (score 1):

This template is expected to be rendered as a full page. To include it, it might be more convenient to render [the controller action](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/16b04c49af05dd3fb381e4abe04f0e5e231ac76d/Controller/SecurityController.php#L64).

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
```

Comment: Cool, I want to do the same with the registration template `{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}`but it render all the page content. How can I just render the form?

Comment: that's a bit more tricky as it would require overriding the bundle - see @Letsrock 's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36885036/558866